# Regular Expression with Constrains

Tags: c#, regex

How can I build a regular expression for the following patterns:

- [Single Character][Numbers] or [Numbers][Single Character] > exp: A123 or 123A
- [Characters][Numbers] or [Numbers][Characters] > exp: AA123 or 123AA

For constrains, I want to make sure there is no mix between character(s) and numbers in the middle. For instance, 123A123 - 123AA123 - 1A1 - A1A ...etc

I want to restrict the string so we can have input that starts with character(s) followed by numbers or vice-versa only.

Thanks

Comment: So what you're saying is you're unable to write your own code and unwilling to learn, but you hope somebody here will do it for you.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You should learn the basics of regex:

- To match a single capital letter, use `[A-Z]`.
- To match a number, use `[0-9]`.
- `+` means one or more of the previous character
- "Or" in regex is `|`
- `()` group expressions.
- `^` and `$` anchor the expression.

Put it all together and you get: `^([A-Z]+[0-9]+|[0-9]+[A-Z]+)$`